# How do I shift an entire row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a pretty large table thanks to all the data I've gathered. What I'm wondering is now that I can put this data on a table, sometimes it's just easier to write a MySQL query to update the table. The problem that I'm running into is that I have so many columns that writing a MySQL script to shift the contents of each row to the right is tedious. Right now I'm doing

```
    UPDATE customer.inmates
    SET
    bail = 10_percent
    WHERE LEFT(10_percent, 1) = '$';
```

And then I do another one to do this

```
    UPDATE customer.inmates
    SET
    charge_released = bail
    WHERE LEFT(bail, 1) != '$';
```

You can probably see now that if my table has 50 columns, I'm going to have to write 50 instances of this code to shift a single row. My question is- Is there an easier way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: WHY do you design a table with 50 columns? Don't know of any entity having that many properties. Bet you can have a more efficient schema with less columns.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by _shift the contents of each row to the right_?

Comment: I'm doing data mining. I probably could make it easier by using less rows but there's so much information packed into the pages that I'm mining that I need a lot of columns. It's not a form feed database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple field changes in a single update, as long as you string them together correctly, e.g. for a simple table with fields 'a' through 'e':

```
MariaDB [test]> insert into foo values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from foo;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | e    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | e    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> update foo set a=b, b=c, c=d, d=e, e='f';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test]> select * from foo;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | e    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| b    | c    | d    | e    | f    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The individual update operations are also evaluated left-to-right, and anything read a field which gets changed elsehwere in the query gets the original value of that field:

```
UPDATE foo SET a = b, b = 'bar', c = b
                   ^---original value of b field, 'b'
                      ^---- b-field gets new value
                                 ^--- c still gets original value of b-field:

MariaDB [test]> select * from foo;
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | e    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
| c    | b    | b    | e    | f    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You'll have to write all of your fields into the update query, but it's definitely doable in a single statement, as long as you do your assignments in the correct order.

Comment: You have an error in your example. b should be equal to 'bar'. Besides that, I'm still wondering if there's an easier way. I'm probably just going to compact all the information. I work with smart people so they should know what the tables mean.